# Angular2 - ngIf does not re-render the child component

Tags: angular

I have a login component which is being called from multiple places and has an input to show it as modal or just plain component.

LoginComponent:

```
declare var jQuery: any;
@Component({
    selector: 'login-view',
    templateUrl: '/login/index.html',
    inputs: ['isOpenLoginModal']
})
export class LoginComponent extends BaseConfigurations {
    public isOpenLoginModal: boolean;

    //this method is called from ngOnInit in base class
    public initialize() {
        this.showModal();
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    private showModal(): void {
        if (this.isOpenLoginModal) {
            jQuery("#loginComponentModal").modal('show');
        }
    }
}
```

My Login/index.html template contains a simple bootstrap modal.

My parent component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'upcoming-auction-view',
    templateUrl: '/auctions/upcoming-auctions.html'
})
export class UpcomingAuctionsComponent extends BaseConfigurations {
    private showLoginModal: boolean = false;

    public initialize() {
        this.showLoginModal = false;
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    submitBid(): void {
        if (!this.isAuthenticated) {
            //if user is not authenticated, show login component
            this.showLoginModal = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I have placed my login component in my parent's component like:

```
<login-view *ngIf="showLoginModal === true" [isOpenLoginModal]="true"></login-view>
```

and have a button which calls the submitBid function and updates the flag

```
<input type="submit" class="form-submit primary-btn" value="Place Bid" (click)="submitBid()" />
```

I am updating 'showLoginModal' based on if the user is authenticated or not and have *ngIf to re-render the LoginComponent with modal option. I expect the angular to redraw the  when *ngIf is updated and reopen the modal but it doesn't. It only works once (even if i reset showLoginModal to false before setting it to true).

Comment: Try injecting `cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef` and set it to `false` and then to `true` with calling change detection in between like `this.showLoginModal = false;this.cdRef.detectChanges();this.showLoginModal = true;`

Comment: Have you tried to set showLoginModal as PUBLIC ?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi setting it to public didn't worked.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Implementing change detector as you suggested worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: How to redraw child component from itself (not from a parent component)? I'm trying to, but it is not rendered when I use ngIf + detectChanges...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Injecting `cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef`

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef)  {}
```

and set `showLoginModal` to `false` and then to `true` with calling change detection in between like

```
this.showLoginModal = false;
this.cdRef.detectChanges();
this.showLoginModal = true;
```

This way `ngIf` will re-render even when `showLoginModal` was `true` before the `submitBid()` method was called.